# boost::serialization pre- and post-hooks

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

we're using boost::serialization to serialize and deserialize a class with std::vector< struct > into plain files. The deserialization process creates a new class instance before adding the entries into the vector.
Since we're in a multi threading application we want to ensure proper critical section locking during a deserialization process.

```
    template<class obj>
    inline void                         MetaSerialize(std::string strKey, obj *ptr)
    {
        LOCK(ptr->csAccess);
        std::stringstream stream(std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(stream);
        oa << ptr;
        if (!m_pMetaDB->Put(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), strKey, rocksdb::Slice(stream.str().data(), stream.tellp())).ok())
            LOG_ERROR("Unable to serialize " + strKey, "SM");
    };

    template<class obj>
    void                            MetaDeserialize(std::string strKey, obj *ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr)
        {
            delete *ptr;
            *ptr = NULL;
        }
        std::string strTmp;
        if (m_pMetaDB->Get(rocksdb::ReadOptions(), strKey, &strTmp).ok())
        {
            std::stringstream stream(strTmp);
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(stream);
            ia >> *ptr;
        }
    };
```

My idea was to use pre- and post- functions for the deserialization process in order to lock or unlock the critical section.

Sadly I havent found those hooks or functions in the docs. Are there any I haven't found or is there a different functionality that can be used to establish secure locking through the deserialization process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: serialization knows nothing of concurrency. You'll need to protect then entire deserialisation (and serialization) manually

Comment: that's exactly what I am trying to do. That's why I'm asking about pre and post functions / hooks.

Comment: There are no hooks.

Comment: Why not use standard lock guards? Why not use (exception safe) smart pointers? Why not use the swap idiom. Also, I think you have serious issues deleting the pointer without serialization (it doesn't really make sense for the destructor to do that locking, because it can only lock on the member sync primitive. Any other code blocked waiting for the lock when the destructor ran will be blocked on a stale object. - UB)

Comment: You seem to have LOCK ... is that not a 'hook'?  Have you considered std::mutex?  (as a 'hook'?)  I often prefer a Posix Process Semaphore, set to Local mode (unnamed, unshared), which seems to work well (efficiently). I do not know what you mean by "hooks or functions" .. perhaps you can update your question with more info about the "hooks or functions" you are looking for.

Comment: The LOCK is a macro that uses a special CriticalSection Class for locking - so quite the same as std::mutex with a little bit of advanced functionality.

Right now the variable used for the LOCK method is inside the class that I'm serializing. When calling `ia >> *ptr;` a new instance of the class is made. So the variable used for LOCKing inside the class is useless.
A method would be to move the variable used for locking out of the class that is getting serialized / deserialized.

Comment: Hooks / Functions: I was hoping that there is a MACRO or a function that can be overridden that when `ia >> *ptr;` is called, the old class can be used and only the contents of `std::vector` replaced, or that the value of the LOCKing variable can be moved from one instance to another.
Or that in the pre-hook the instance can be LOCKed and in the post-hook unLOCKed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need hooks.

You don't need to fear someone accidentally invoking your serialization function without proper synchronization (they can always use your object wrong).

Just expose the synchronized serialization operation, which do the locking.